# Why is "of" present for "out of stock" but not "in stock"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

English is my native language, so I know that these combinations *sound* correct to me and other native speakers, at least in the U.S., but why?  Why don't we consistently use or not use "of" for both in and out?  Why are "out stock" and "in of stock" wrong?

Other examples with the same principle:

- *in jail* and *out of jail*
- *in service* and *out of service*
- *in time* and *out of time*

I tried searching this question on this site and search engines, but didn't find an answer.

Comment: My belief (and it is an unsupported opinion so I am presenting it as a comment rather than an answer) is that the language has developed so that 'out of' is the opposite of 'in' and that there is no particular 'reason' why that happened. It is interesting to note that something similar happens in French ('hors de' is the normal opposite of 'dans' so far as I know) but not in German. Perhaps 'out of' merely followed the French convention as a result of the Norman Conquest. There are dialects where the 'of' is sometimes dropped as in "I got it out me pocket" but these are non-standard English.

Comment: I think the only answer here is: *Because.*

Comment: I haven't researched this, but doesn't British English observe a somewhat similar split in wording between "indoors" and "out of doors"?

Answer (score 5):

It's because "in" is a preposition, while "out" is not*. In your examples, "out" is being used as an adjective or an adverb.

To have a true opposite for the phrase "in X", we need another prepositional phrase. Some languages have a single word for "out of" (the example that comes to mind right now is Latin, where "ex" means "out of"). But in English, we don't have a single-word opposite for "in". Sometimes we juxtapose the words "in" and "out" and treat them as opposites, but this is usually when they are directional adverbs (go *in* the door, go *out* the door) rather than prepositional states of being (*in* the room, *out of* the room).

So we say "out of X" simply because we would never* say "out X" and we don't have a word for "ex X" like in Latin.

Perhaps if you are craving some extra parallelism in your prepositional phrases, you could start using "into" as an opposite for "out of". While "into" has a slightly different meaning than "in", it could make for some semantically interesting examples!

- into jail (upon initial incarceration)
- into service (immediately after successful repairs?)
- into time (...??)

EDIT: I forgot to mention, in many (most?) cases, "out" is usually analyzed as an adverb. "We ran out of milk." could be abbreviated as "We ran out." This shows that "out" is describing the verb "ran", instead of being inherently tied to the preposition "of".

*Please don't misunderstand what I'm saying! It is in fact possible to use "out" as a standalone preposition, meaning something like "through". Using "out" as a preposition used to be more common than it is today. In 1830, Alfred, Lord Tennyson wrote in "Adeline":
"Thy roselips and full blue eyes / Take the heart from **out** my breast."

Nowadays the use of "out" as a preposition is more restrictive to certain phrases, for example "walk out the door" or "look out the window", and almost exclusively means "through". In contrast, today we would say "take the heart from **out of** my breast".

Comment: It seems likely that the single English preposition is *outside* (which doesn't take *of,* at least in British English).

Comment: *It's because "in" is a preposition, while "out" is not. * You should say what "out" is.

Comment: "Out" is an adverb. "In" can also be used as an adverb, but in the phrases from the questioner, "in" is being used as a preposition.

Comment: Where does it say that the word, out, is nowhere a preposition?  I think that it's better to keep, in, versus, out, as opposites ... even if it means that a bus "coming into service" now means it's "in(to) service".  Something may be in, or out, as into, or out of.  Otherwise we end up with more stuff like the theoretical physics about there not being a down direction (big crunch) to the universe.

Comment: I didn't say it's "nowhere" a preposition. The problem with these conversations is that people want simple one-size-fits-all answers, but English doesn't work that way. When people use the word "out" in expressions like "out of milk", they are not using "out" as a preposition but as an adjective or adverb (depending on context). It is possible to use "out" as a preposition.

Comment: They're both prepositions, but they have different affordances. As @YourGrammarGuide points out, the usual object of _out_ is a path, not a container. _In_ defines containers and gets used in container metaphors (like this one) everywhere. _Out_ is a different matter and applies more often to movement than to position; if you want to implicate a container you need another preposition. Of course this is not logical, but it's the way things work now.

Comment: @JohnLawler You make a good point. The line between semantics and syntax is not always as clear as we might like. Your analysis is certainly reasonable.

Words are words, and while we can try to put words into different categories, at the end of the day the "truth" of language lies in the unspoken competency of native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition "out" usually means "out through" (e.g.: "He went out the back door."). Therefore, you can't say "That product is out stock." On the other hand, "in" is a very common preposition with a variety of meanings, such as in the phrase "in stock." However, I don't know exactly why those prepositions developed as they did. BoldBen's suggestion (that they did so due to the influence of a foreign language, like French) is interesting.

Comment: +1 Right on. Look at the usages and constructions, not easy parallels.

Comment: "All kinds of interesting questions which the science knowledge only adds to the excitement, the mystery and the awe of a flower. It only adds. I don’t understand how it subtracts." Richard Feynman